# Tips for securing our "public" code repository server

Tags: security, perforce, vpn, public

I'm working at an IT company where we have used Perforce for years as our code repository system, in our internal company network. Because we are starting to work with an offsite company we are looking into ways of making our Perforce server accessible via the internet.

The most obvious way for me to do this is setup a VPN server on our linux gateway server and allow access through that. Obviously this works but seems very unsafe. If a VPN key of a certain user falls in the wrong hands they can access our code-repository AND our complete internal network.

My first thought was to create a Perforce proxy server (they supply software for this) and host this behind another gateway, with a VPN server. This shields the real Perforce server and our network better. The obvious problem here is that the *proxy* needs access to our perforce server, meaning the two networks needs to be connected anyway.

Our company is rather small, so taking into account we don't have a huge resource pool to spend on this, how would you approach this?

thanks a lot in advance,
Fred.

Comment: Consider posting this question to http://security.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying the behavior and configuration of your current internal server, perhaps you should set up a second Perforce server, and use that server **only** for the interactions between your team and your offsite partner.

Include explicit steps in your workflow to periodically "publish" code from your internal server to your external server, and similar steps to periodically "consume" the offsite company's work by copying their changes back to your internal server and re-submitting them there.

Additionally, there are companies which offer a hosted Perforce service, so you don't even have to operate this external Perforce server yourself; you can let the hosting company manage the operational aspects of this code-sharing server.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to put the official Perforce server in an outside locked-down server.  That is to say, everyone accesses Perforce at the outside server, which has Perforce and only Perforce on it.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not really on option for us, since this would mean all Perforce access happens over the internet. Even for people working in the office. Most of the time, we work with video and texture materials, sometimes several GBs in size, this would hamper our productivity.